# Can't add local variable to list inside a while loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For some reason, I can't get to add any kind of element to the Tuple list "objLockSpDict" from the "InstantiateSelResult" method, which is successfully called when the while loop should end. I can't ever get it to work inside that method or the loop itself, although it does work on your typical methods called by start, update, etc...

````
List<System.Tuple<GameObject, Transform>> objLockSpDict = new List<System.Tuple<GameObject, Transform>>();

randLocalSpIndex = UniqueRandomNoList(localSpawnPoints.Count, objectsToSpawn);

for (var x = 0; x < randLocalSpIndex.Count; x++)
{
    bool approvedSel = false;

    while (approvedSel == false)
    {
        System.Tuple<OSpPool, Transform> selResult = selectPoolObject(x); //select a random pooled obj.

        ObjectSpawner.Pool foundPool = null;
        for (var y = 0; y < oSp.poolLists.Count; y++) //find the pool where the selected obj belongs.
            foundPool = oSp.poolLists[y].pools.FirstOrDefault(x => x.tag == selResult.Item1.poolTag);

        ObjectSpawner.PoolList foundPoolList = oSp.poolLists.FirstOrDefault(x => x.pools.Contains(foundPool)); //find the list of pools where the foundPool belongs.
        
        //CONDITIONS REQUIRED TO SPAWN THE SELECTED OBJ, if not met -> try again with another obj.
        if(foundPoolList.ENABLED)

        if ((foundPool.poolProperties.reqDifficulty.x <= oSp.gM.gameDifficulty) && 
            (foundPool.poolProperties.reqDifficulty.y >= oSp.gM.gameDifficulty))

        if((oSp.gM.GetComponent<Score>().score >= foundPool.poolProperties.reqScore))

        if (foundPool.activeCount < foundPool.size)
        {
            InstantiateSelResult(selResult, foundPool, thisInstance); //spawn selected obj.
            approvedSel = true; //stop the loop
        }
    }
}
void InstantiateSelResult(System.Tuple<OSpPool, Transform> selResult, ObjectSpawner.Pool pool, Transform thisInstance)
{
    pool.activeCount += 1;
    Vector3 InsRelativePos = thisInstance.position + selResult.Item2.position;

    GameObject localSpObj = oSp.InstantiateFromPool(pool, InsRelativePos, Quaternion.identity, oSp.spObjHolder);
    Debug.LogWarningFormat("localSpObj = "+(localSpObj != null)+" | selresult_1 = "+(selResult.Item1 != null)+" | selresult_2 = "+(selResult.Item2 != null)+" | thisInstance = "+(thisInstance != null)); //[All appear as TRUE]
        
    objLockSpDict.Add(new System.Tuple<GameObject, Transform>(localSpObj, selResult.Item2)); //[NOT WORK!!!]
}```
````

Comment: Is the debug statement on the line above firing?

Comment: Also, it's really confusing that you have a variable named dict that is not in fact a dict. Even if you are using it as a lookup table, I'd suggest a clearer name.

Comment: Did you debug the code? What did you notice during debugging? `InstantiateSelResult` this method is called? Do you get any error on line `objLockSpDict.Add`? How do you confirm that the Tuple is not added to the list?

Comment: || First, sorry for the name, it was a dictionary before, but switched it into a tuple list cause dictionaries can't take duplicates.  || Second, the debug above the line that adds to the list does execute properly, appearing true on each of the statements in it.  || Third, there are literally no error results, at least coming from the Unity console.  || Fourth, I did debug the code a lot, I know the method is called because the debug line inside it gets executed & the object gets instanced, and I get up-to-date counting of the number of elements found inside the list, which always result 0.